# MySQL Custom Function To Select Record

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am trying to create a custom function in MySQL that will take a UNIX date timestamp and convert it back to an actual date and in that function SELECT a value from a table based on that date.

```
Create function fiscal(current TIMESTAMP)
Returns INT
Begin
    Declare select_date DATE;
    Declare select_year INT(11);
    SET select_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(current);
    SET select_date = DATE_FORMAT(select_date, '%m-%d-%y');
    SET select_year = (SELECT Year FROM DateInfo WHERE DateInfo_ID = select_date);
    Return select_year;
END
```

It returns a NULL value.

Comment: May be the return value is not INT.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the data type of the return value in the RETURNS statement. It can be any valid MySQL data types.

The `RETURN` statement returns a value to the caller. Whenever the `RETURN` statement is reached, the stored function’s execution is terminated immediately.

For the same input parameters, if the stored function returns the same result, it is considered deterministic and not deterministic otherwise.

```
DELIMITER $$
Create function fiscal(current TIMESTAMP)
Returns INT(11) NOT DETERMINISTIC
Begin
    Declare select_date DATE;
    Declare select_year INT(11);
    SET select_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(current);
    SET select_date = DATE_FORMAT(select_date, '%m-%d-%y');
    SET select_year = (SELECT Year FROM DateInfo WHERE DateInfo_ID = select_date);
    Return (select_year);
END
```

OR may be the return value is not INT.
In such a case, try this instead:

```
...
Returns VARCHAR(10)
...
Declare select_year VARCHAR(10);
...
```

Comment: I receive 2 warnings. 1st Warning is "Data truncated for column 'current' at row 1".  2nd Warning is "Data truncated for column 'select_date' at row 1".

Comment: Try `DATE` instead of `current`. Is it still returns `NULL` or just the warnings or the truncated result or what?